# Undefined index exception in many to one doctrine relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Worker entity

```
/**
 * Worker
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="worker")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Worker
 {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     private $id;
}
```

and an Invoice entity like this:

```
/**
 * Invoice
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Invoice")
 */
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Worker")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fkWorker", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
     private $worker;
}
```

So in my controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$invoice = $em->getRepository('SkaLab\Bundle\FrontEndBundle\Entity\Invoice')->find(8);
```

But i don't understand this last row return an exception like this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Invoice
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

How can i figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Although it won't fix your problem, for good practice I'd change your `Worker` class so that it's defined with the capital letter, i.e. `@ORM\Table(name="Worker")` to ensure consistency.

Comment: thank you Dom, i try to change that but don't fix my problem

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Could you post a bit more of your code?

Comment: Wrong. It's just the table name and it can be lowercase

Comment: Thanks chalasr, I've amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The Invoice entity has no identifier. 
Do you just haven't copy/paste it ?

Then, try to call your entity like :

```
   getRepository('SkalableFrontEndBundle:Invoice')
```

instead of the full namespace, it can be a typo in it.

If it persists, share the full log of the error in your question.

Comment: There is no need to break the design of the class by making properties `protected`. Doctrine works pretty well with `private` properties.

Comment: thank you xabbuh and chalasr. i try to cache getRepository parameter, but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you a $id in your Invoice entity ? It is not visible in your question